Why Is Datepicker Calendar Icon Not Showing in Shield UI?
I am working on two simple single page applications that are using the Shield UI basic JavaScript framework to add datepicker functionality.  Both projects are setup essentially the same, with slight differences in my added CSS classes and the way components are laid out / structured.  My datepicker is working in both applications, but in one the calendar icon is displayed, and the other it isn't.  I've verified that I have the proper CSS and JavaScript files are present in both projects, and both have the Shield UI sprite.  What am I missing that might be causing this?
Here's the relevant Head links in project 1 (note that I pull the all.min.css file out of the associated theme):
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.min.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="md-label-div hidden" id="insurance-div">
    <span class="no-margin-top md-label-date">Insurance expiration date:</span>
    <span class="md-label">
       <input id="datepicker1" class="md-input-date" name="insurance-date">
    </span>
  </div>    
</body>
<script>
   ons.ready(function(){
      $(function () {
        $("#datepicker1").shieldDatePicker({
</script>

...and here is project 2 (this is the one where the icon is working properly):
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div style="padding-top: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
     <p style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
     </p>
     <p style="margin-top: 0;">
        <input id="date" class="date" />
     </p>
   </div>
</body>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#date").shieldDatePicker();
   });  
</script>

Also, I'm wondering if there is any lightweight alternative using only CSS and the HTML5 datepicker that I'd have control over the styling of.  From the little bit of research I did today it doesn't seem possible without rolling my own in JavaScript, but if anyone has any suggestions....it seems a bit silly to be adding jQuery and Shield UI to my project for a handful of datepickers.

Drat - right as I was posting this I noticed that my CSS file was loading after the relevant JavaScript files in one of the projects and thought that might be it, but unfortunately no dice.

There is one other potentially relevant difference: I'm also using Onsen UI as the single page app framework.  The project that isn't working is breaking out onsen templates as separate HTML files, while the one that's working has all templates loaded into a single HTML file.  Updating my tags to include Onsen UI...
